# separates the string and display just first value

Tags: excel, vba, split

Developing a function which separates the string and i want to display the first value after = that is 16 instead of entire separated string.

I hope to get some help thanks.

```
Sub Split()

    Dim arr() As String
    
    arr = Split("KeyNo = ,16,17,18", ",")

    Dim name As Variant
    For Each name In arr
        Debug.Print name
    Next

End Sub
```

and this one also

```
Sub Split2()

    Dim arr() As String
    
    arr = Split("KeyNo = 16,17,18", ",")

    Dim name As Variant
    For Each name In arr
        Debug.Print name
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Split("KeyNo = 16,17,18", ",")(0)` will give you "KeyNo = 16" and  `Split("KeyNo = 16,17,18", ",")(1) `will give you 17 and so on ... it separates values on comma and returns zero based index

Comment: It gives `Type Mismatch error` on this line `arr = Split("BookNo = ,16,17,18", ",")(1)` @Naresh

Comment: 'Instead of `Dim arr() As String` use `Dim arr As String` then arr will be those values. Try this ... `Debug.Print Split("KeyNo = 16,17,18", ",")(0)`  and `Debug.Print Split("KeyNo = 16,17,18", ",")(1)`then you will understand

Comment: Then new error appears `Compile Error For each may only iterate over a collection object or an array`

Comment: You don't need a loop to extract just desired value. With index as mentioned above you can extract value of any position (0 based).. If you want all values one by one then you need array. ... In your first code `Debug.Print Split("KeyNo = ,16,17,18", ",")(1)` will give you 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of the `SplitAndDisplay()` code below is the following:

- split by separator and write the result to myArr;
- loop from `lbound(myArr)` to `ubound(myArr) - 1`, to make sure that there is always a next item;
- if the `splitAfter()` is found, then display the next item;
- if not, return `-1`;

---

```
Sub Split16()

    Dim textInput As String
    textInput = "KeyNo = ,16,17,18"
    
    Dim result As String
    result = SplitAndDisplay(textInput, ",", "=")
    Debug.Print result
        
End Sub

Public Function SplitAndDisplay(textInput As String, mySeparator As String, splitAfter As String)
    
    Dim myArr As Variant
    myArr = Split(textInput, mySeparator)
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr) - 1
        If InStr(myArr(i), "=") Then
            SplitAndDisplay = myArr(i + 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    
    SplitAndDisplay = -1
    
End Function
```

Comment: thank you. If string is like `"KeyNo = 16,17,18"` instead of `"KeyNo = ,16,17,18"` then how to get 16.

Comment: @IntoLearn - from this line - *separates the string and i want to display the first value after* I assume that you are not supposed to take 16 in this case, but simply the next item. Otherwise, what is the idea of the splitter?

Comment: I got your point i was wrong Thank you. One more thing that how to use this code to create a loop. I have multiple Id's in that format in `Col"B"` where i am using them to match the data from other sheet by putting first values like `16` manually in that loop`For r = 2 To LastRow` then `KeyID = ws.Cells(r, "B").Value` @Vityata

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is with Regular Expressions:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Test()
   MsgBox ExtractFirstNumber("KeyNo = ,16,17,18")
   MsgBox ExtractFirstNumber("KeyNo = 16,17,18")
End Sub

Private Function ExtractFirstNumber(ByVal Value As String) As String
   Dim regex As regExp
   Dim matches As MatchCollection

   Set regex = New regExp
   regex.Pattern = "\d+"
   regex.Global = True

   If regex.Test(Value) Then
      Set matches = regex.Execute(Value)
      ExtractFirstNumber = matches(0)
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want the *16* whether there is a comma following the *"="* or not.  If the comma is absent, just put it in and then use `Split()`:

```
Sub splittt()
    s = "KeyNo = ,16,17,18"
    If InStr(s, "= ,") = 0 Then
        s = Replace(s, "= ", "= ,")
    End If
    
    arr = Split(s, ",")
    MsgBox arr(1)
End Sub
```

[image]